# Scala Java interoperability with val

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In scala, if we have a class say,

```
case class B(b: Int)
object B {
    def main(args: Array[String] {
        val b = B(1)
        b.b = 2 // ** compile time error here **
    }
}
```

would give an error saying, when compile with `scalac B.scala`

```
error: reassignment to val
b.b = 2 
    ^
```

Everything is fine till here.

However, if I have a java class `A.java`:

```
public class A {
     public int a;
     public A(int a) {this.a = a;}
     public void setA(int a_) {this.a = a_;}
     public String toString() {return "A: " + a;}
}
```

first compile it with `javac A.java`,
then use it in scala with `val`:

```
object B {
    def main(args: Array[String] {
        val a = new A(1)
        println("Before assignment: " + a)
        a.a = 2 // ** No error here **
        println("After assignment: " + a)
    }
}
```

compile `B.scala` with `scalac B.scala` and run with `scala B`. No error occurs.

Does it break intention of `val` in scala?

If I want to, when using java class in scala, maintain the fixed value of instance `a`, what can I do?

Or there actually is some documentation mentioning this behavior?

```
Environment: Scala version 2.11.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_75).
Centos 6.6
```

**Edit**

Thank you everyone for your reply.

While I am well aware that by making the field final:
`public final int a;`, immutability can be achieved.

I'm not hoping to solve this problem by modifying java code.
Imagine that I'm using third party java libraries that I can no way modify their code, yet I want making sure my code won't accidentally modify third-party's internal state, hence come the `val`.

In addition, by disassembling the `.class` file using `javap -c`, it can be seen clearly that scala is not making `B.b` immutable by inserting `final` to class `B`.

Or maybe someone explaining the "magic" behind `val` would be helpful

Comment: You should define `b` like this: `case class B(var b: Int)`

Answer (score 2):

Clearly in your Java class `A`, the member `a` is both public and mutable. To treat a Java variable as Scala `val`, you can make it `final` in your Java class.

Also remember that Scala too has `var` which has essentially same behaviour as Java variables ( except for `final` ones ).

**EDIT 1**

Define `B` like so:

```
case class B(val b: Int, var c: Int)
```

And then check the compiled class definition

```
$ javap B
Compiled from "B.scala"
public class B implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable {
  public static scala.Option<scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>> unapply(B);
  public static B apply(int, int);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  public int b();
  public int c();
  public int copy$default$1();
  public int copy$default$2();
  public void c_$eq(int);
  public B copy(int, int);
  public java.lang.String productPrefix();
  public int productArity();
  public java.lang.Object productElement(int);
  public scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.Object> productIterator();
  public boolean canEqual(java.lang.Object);
  public int hashCode();
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public B(int, int);
}
```

Thing to note here is that for member 'c' you will have `public void c_$eq(int);` but for member `b` there is no such method. In fact in Scala, the assignment turns out to be a method call.

I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In scala, I don't have to specify the accessibility of `B.b`. With `val`, compiler would happily throw out error when reassigning `B.b = 2`. However compile time checking is not ensured when using java class. I wonder if there anyway to prevent me to reassign `a.a = 3` if `val` is used?

Comment: You defined `val a = new A(1)`, which is fine. However `a.a` is not a `val` for scala. It is effectively a `var` for Scala. To make the compiler generate error, you could either hide it `private A.a`, or make it final `final a`.

Comment: By examining `B.class` with `javap B.class -c`, it is clearly that everything generated by the compile is `public`. So maybe there is something other than `public/private`?

Comment: Check *EDIT1* in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from line `val a = new A(1)` in `object B`. It means that you cannot reassign value to your variable `a` but it's completely ok to reassign any field of `a`. This can be limited by marking a filed be final

Try making `public int a` `final` in your java class as following

```
public class A {
   public final int a;
   public A(int a) {this.a = a;}
   //public void setA(int a_) {this.a = a_;} //Compilation error here. Cannot assign to a final field
   public String toString() {return "A: " + a;}
}
```

It will enforce that field `a` of class `A` cannot be reassigned.